# WebDriver | Chrome Webdriver does not open the Webplayer of Spotify

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I am currently trying to create a bot that will log into Spotify accounts and automatically play a song through a proxy.
For this I use the Chrome Webdriver.
If I open the link of my song without being logged in, the web player of Spotify .
But after logging in to an account the webplayer doesn't work anymore but it's just a black background.
So I wanted to ask you if you know how to fix this

[This is the black background of the Spotify Webplayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmx2M.png)

```
public void run() {
        while(valid) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int delay = rand.nextInt(max_delay - min_delay + 1) + min_delay;
            try {
                Thread.sleep((delay*1000)/5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                
            }
            
            String proxylist = getOutOf("proxy.txt");
            String account = getOutOf("accounts.txt");
            String email = account.split(":")[0];
            String password  = account.split(":")[1];
            
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Spotify-Bot\\chromedriver.exe");
            
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
            proxy.setHttpProxy(proxylist);
        
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
            
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
            
            driver.get(track);
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep((delay*1000)/3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                
            }
            
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#main > div > div.Root__top-container > div.Root__top-bar > header > div:nth-child(4) > button._3f37264be67c8f40fa9f76449afdb4bd-scss._1f2f8feb807c94d2a0a7737b433e19a8-scss")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep((delay*1000)/4);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                
            }
            
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-username")).sendKeys(email);
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep((delay*1000)/5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                
            }
            
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-password")).sendKeys(password);
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep((delay*1000)/8);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                
            }
            
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-button")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep((delay*1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                
            }
            
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: can you add a break point into your code and open browser's console before accessing that page? Maybe you can see any valuable information in Console tab. I'm thinking that could be a "defensive" feature from Spotify to avoid having allowing bots.